# Show, activate and stop indetermined progress indicator

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, timing, nstask, nsprogressindicator

I'm having some issues with showing a **progress indicator** whenever a button is clicked, and then stop and hide the indicator when a **NSTask** is completed.

This should be the timeline:
1- Button clicked
2- shows progress indicator (from originally hidden state)
3- activates progress indicator
4- activate associated NSTask
5- Continue showing the indicator until the NSTask is completed
6- after the completion of the NSTask, hide the progress indicator.

I know how to get a progress indicator to animate etc. I just do not know how to combine these with the NSTask completing thing..

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSTask`'s `terminationHandler` property to set a block to execute when the task terminates. In that block stop/hide your progress indicator.

**Addendum (see comments)**

In rough outline:

```
NSTask *myTask = ...;
NSProgressIndicator *myIndicator = ...;

myTask.terminationHandler = ^(NSTask *theTask) { [myIndicator stopAnimation:nil]; };
```

Note that the handler is passed the `NSTask` in case it needs to access information from it. Also `nil` is passed as the `sender` to `stopAnimation:` - you usually pass `self` but that would cause a retain cycle and what object is actually invoking the method isn't important.

Comment: Thanks! I have to give you accepted answer because you were first.

Comment: Would you mind giving a tiny example of how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set a block to the `NSTask`'s `terminationHandler`.

[NSTask terminationHandler](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSTask/terminationHandler)